# FUNCIÓN PARA IMPRESIÓN DE UNA SECCION CODIGO

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, impresión

**PRODUCCIÓN**

Mi sistema desarrollado lo que hace es obtener los datos personales de una persona que va a ingresar a cierto lugar en donde este implementado, en este caso es una clinica.

> Hardware: Impresora de etiquetas **Dymo450** y lector de código de barras para el tipo **CC PDF417**.

**PROBLEMÁTICA**

Resulta que en lo que he desarrollado hago uso de un proceso de impresion por medio del navegador, lo que al principio habia resultado bien, hasta que nos dimos cuenta de que la empresa contratante del servicio realiza el registro de una persona pero no imprime la etiqueta (Cancelando la impresion desde la vista de impresión), que en este caso es el consumible por el cual está enfocado el Software.

**SOLUCIONES NO COMPLETADAS**

- Traté de integrar por medio del SDK de la impresora Dymo450 con el
  fin de hacer directo el proceso de impresión sin usar un
  "intermediario", pero me encontré con una barrera a la hora de la
  compatibilidad entre lenguajes.
- Traté de bloquear la vista previa del navegador, lo cual no es que sea lo mas viable dado que tocaría modificar el acceso directo del navegador de la persona que esté usando el aplicativo web, además de que no fue posible solucionarlo con el comando que se debe adicionar al acceso directo [Ejemplo más claro aquí](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/JJNzUxxtMio;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/authorid%243AAPn2wQc4XjuNw-oPI5lS5yG8xTAhhKQcDhY7WrvITSksnbovCjaQnH6G74ez-CiBTNEEZw22ybgr%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false):

> --disable-print-preview

**PREGUNTA**

A continuación muestro la función que estoy usando para la impresión:

- ¿Es posible qué por medio de la funcion se pueda obtener el valor de cuándo se cancela el proceso de impresión por medio del navegador?

**MUESTRA IMPRESIÓN**

[image: DISEÑO DE LA ETIQUETA]

**CÓDIGO**

Funcion que se encarga de obtener el contenido de una  división(div) de HTML, en la cual por medio de los ngModels obtengo los datos y se plasman antes de ser enviados a la **DB**.

```
  //FUNCION QUE SE ENCARGA DE IMPRIMIR EL FORMULARIO
  $scope.impresionFormulario = function(formularioPersona)
  {
     var ficha=document.getElementById(formularioPersona);
     var ventimp=window.open(' ','popimpr');
     ventimp.document.write(ficha.innerHTML);
     ventimp.document.close();
     ventimp.print();
     ventimp.close();
  }
```

**CONSOLA DE LA VARIABLE ventimp**

Resultado de la variable, pero independientemente de que se cancele la impresión, se obtiene el mismo resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `window.print()` no devuelve nada, es como `alert()`. Es decir, bloquea la ejecución y pide al navegador que muestra la ventana de diálogo para imprimir el documento actual, pero no se tiene ningún control sobre dicha ventana: el usuario puede imprimir o no y nosotros nunca lo sabremos.

**Actualización**

Mirando cuál era la impresora, me he dado cuenta de que yo me he enfrentado a este mismo escenario, así que te explico la solución que implementamos:

Conectamos nuestra impresora a la red local del servidor y la configuramos usando CUPS. Para usarla, generamos los PDF como ficheros temporales y, ejecutábamos desde el shell de Linux `lp <nombre_del_fichero>`. Eso envía a la impresora la orden de imprimir. Puedes añadir parámetros extras para configurar detalles (márgenes, orientación...)

Comment: Entonces que otra opcion podria realizar para solucionar lo que ocurre?

Comment: Intenta imprimir desde el servidor sin usar el SDK, mediante comandos. Otra opción es crear tu propio comando con un lenguaje compatible con el SDK de la impresora y llamarlo desde tu servidor.

Comment: La verdad, es una opción pero mi conocimiento no llega hasta allá. Estoy leyendo y buscando al respecto para tratar de usar la impresora desde la parte del servidor. Gracias por su aporte, me abrio una nueva forma de buscarle solucion a lo que busco.